# Auto exit Telnet command back to prompt without human intervention ^] quit close exit code 1

Tags: linux, telnet, exit, exit-code, connection-close

I'm running `telnet` command on a host for a given port (which is open), it returns 0 (success).

For trying telnet manually, I type the following command, then I press control+bracket i.e. `^]`, then press `Enter` key, then I get to `telnet>` prompt, where if I type `close` or `quit`, it comes back to the `$` prompt and seeing exit status of last command shows `0` for (success) as port 2878 is open (as per the telnet command's output).

```
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ telnet `hostname` 2878
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myvagrant.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> close
Connection closed.
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ echo $?
0
```

Now, I wanted to run the same operation without any human intervention i.e.  I don't want to manually give `^]` and press `Enter` key to come to the `telnet>` prompt, then enter `close` (or `quit`) telnet command to finally come back to the `$` prompt.

For this, I tried using `echo -e` command's option and giving `^]`, `\n` (for new line character i.e. `Enter` key) and `close` command (for `telnet>` prompt so that I come back to `$` prompt). Doing this, kind of worked as expected but for the exit status of last command `echo $?`, I'm getting `1` (instead of **0**). **Why?**

```
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ echo -e "^]\nclose" | telnet `hostname` 2878
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myvagrant.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ 
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ echo $?
1
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $
```

**or** tried the here-doc method as well, but not sure why it's returning `1` (as exit code) for a valid port which is open.

```
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ telnet `hostname` 2878 <<GIGA
> echo ^]
> echo close
> GIGA
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myvagrant.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny] $ echo $?
1
[vagrant@myvagrant ~/aks/always-latest-ws-sunny] $
```

How can I automatically exit from telnet if the port is open and get `0` as exit code? If there's a way to capture the output of the previous command, may be I can grep the '*Connection closed by foreign host.*' string to mark it successful (0).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A slight improvement to the answer provided by Matthew above which allows you to use it inside shell scripts:

```sh
$ echo -e '\x1dclose\x0d' | telnet google.com 80
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

telnet> close
Connection closed.
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Matthew's answer doesn't work for me. This one works. I am still surprised why.

Comment: Work for me beautifully!

Comment: @Maxim Akhmedov Nice!!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the clean way to do it

```
echo -n | telnet `hostname` 2878
```

or,

```
telnet `hostname` 2878 </dev/null
```

For more info on this behavior see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609763/interesting-behaviour-of-echo-n-command-when-used-in-the-beginning/60609809#60609809)

Answer (score 1):

```
╭─ ~
╰» echo "^]close^M" | telnet localhost 22; echo $?
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

telnet> close
Connection closed.
0
```

To enter the `^]` and `^M` characters, press `ctrl+v` `ctrt+]` and `ctrl+v` `ctrl+m` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You may need other linux package like `expect` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, expect is prob. the way to go.  "Expect is a tool for automating interactive applications according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what
the correct response should be."

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Expect`, I guess using the **HERE** document (<

```
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ telnet_result=$(telnet `hostname` 2878 <<GIGA
echo ^]
echo close
GIGA
); echo $telnet_result | grep "Escape character is '^]'"; echo $?
Connection closed by foreign host.
 Escape character is '^]'.
0
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $
```

and for a bad/invalid/non-open port, the same gives `1` (as expected).

```
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $ telnet_result=$(telnet `hostname` 287811111 <<GIGA
echo ^]
echo close
GIGA
); echo $telnet_result | grep "Escape character is '^]'"; echo $?
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
1
[vagrant@myvagrant /tmp] $
```

Comment: Nah, I don't like this solution that much, but it's working as I used 2-3 operations at least.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I used for this :

for i in list
do
for j in list1
do
sleep 2|timeout --signal=9 3 telnet $i $j
done
done