# Ansible - telnet fails - command / shell module - rc return code 1 failed: true

Tags: ansible, telnet, exit-code, ansible-2.x

This question does have some history from this post: [Auto exit Telnet command back to prompt without human intervention ^] quit close exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476089/auto-exit-telnet-command-back-to-prompt-without-human-intervention-quit-close)

Btw, I'm trying to test a port using telnet command where the port can be OPEN or NOT. How can I do the same in Ansible?

I tried the following but (whether port is open or not open/it's invalid), Ansible always says it `'failed': true` in the results or output dictionary variable and return code `'rc': 1`

I tried `command` module and `shell` module as well but it didn't work.

HOW should I do to get Ansible run this `telnet` command successfully so that next actions (defined in the playbook's tasks) can work.

**My playbook snippet:**

```
- name: Ensure collector agent's proxy_address and proxy_port is open
  #command: "echo -e \"^]\\nclose\"| telnet {{ proxy_address }} {{ proxy_port }}"
  #shell: "echo -e \"^]\\nclose\" | telnet `hostname` {{ proxy_port }}"
  shell: "telnet `hostname` {{ proxy_port }}"
  register: telnet_result
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags:
   - giga

- debug: msg="telnet output result was = {{ telnet_result }}"
  tags:
   - giga
```

Running `ansible-playbook` using the following command, gives me the follwoing error (if I use either of the `shell` commands listed above).

**PS:** File `myplaybook.yml` is just calling a role `mytask`.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -l localhost myplaybook.yml --extra-vars "proxy_port=2878" -t giga -vvv
```

**Output:**

```
TASK [mytask : Ensure collector agent's proxy_address and proxy_port is open] ***
task path: /home/vagrant/aks/ansible/roles/mytask/tasks/install_telegraf.yml:3
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmpoVYTlY TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488/command
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488/ /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488/command && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-asjgqzogcakikhnvwamwruivfbutphtz; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488/command; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483580659.49-61726964686488/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "telnet `hostname` 2878", "delta": "0:00:00.006042", "end": "2017-01-05 01:44:19.590362", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "telnet `hostname` 2878", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-01-05 01:44:19.584320", "stderr": "Connection closed by foreign host.", "stdout": "Trying 127.0.0.1...\r\nConnected to myvagrant.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.", "stdout_lines": ["Trying 127.0.0.1...", "Connected to myvagrant.", "Escape character is '^]'."], "warnings": []}
...ignoring

TASK [mytask : debug] *************************************
task path: /home/vagrant/aks/ansible/roles/mytask/tasks/install_telegraf.yml:12
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "telnet output result was = {u'changed': True, u'end': u'2017-01-05 01:44:19.590362', u'stdout': u\"Trying 127.0.0.1...\\r\\nConnected to myvagrant.\\r\\nEscape character is '^]'.\", u'cmd': u'telnet `hostname` 2878', 'failed': True, u'delta': u'0:00:00.006042', u'stderr': u'Connection closed by foreign host.', u'rc': 1, 'stdout_lines': [u'Trying 127.0.0.1...', u'Connected to myvagrant.', u\"Escape character is '^]'.\"], u'start': u'2017-01-05 01:44:19.584320', u'warnings': []}"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`failed_when: <your_condition>`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure), for example:

```
failed_when: false
```

---

Besides, you seem like trying to mimic [`wait_for`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html) module.

Comment: That won't help, being `failed_when: false` (in all cases i.e. especially for an incorrect/port which is not open). But, I liked your answer so will accept it :) When I changed it to: `failed_when: "'Connection refused' in telnet_result.stderr"` in my case, it worked successfully without failing for a port (which was correct/open) and did fail for an incorrect/not-open port (which is expected). Right?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant by "`your_condition`" because you have not specified your goal in the question; and `false` was an example. You could as well continue and use registered output to control other tasks.

Comment: Yes, that I saw using .stdout/stderr or etc dict variables from the register + if I use `ignore_errors: yes`. `failed_when: <condition>` worked great! thanks.