# Interesting behaviour of echo -n command when used in the beginning

Tags: bash, shell, openssl, echo, telnet

I'm seeing one interesting behaviour with some commands which need manual interruption when piped with echo -n command.

```
bash-3.2$ openssl
OpenSSL> exit

bash-3.2$ echo -n | openssl
OpenSSL> bash-3.2$

bash-3.2$ telnet 10.207.139.8 22
Trying 10.207.139.8...
Connected to 10.207.139.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
^]
telnet> Connection closed.

bash-3.2$ echo -n | telnet 10.207.139.8 22
Trying 10.207.139.8...
Connected to 10.207.139.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
bash-3.2$
```

When used with echo -n it will not prompt for user input. What is happening behind the scene?

The man page of echo command says this

```
 -n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string, as is done by iBCS2
           compatible systems.  Note that this option as well as the effect of `\c' are implementation-defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'')
           as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for maximum portability are strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to suppress the newline
           character.
```

Answer (score 4):

When you connect two commands into a pipeline, `foo | bar`, the output of the first command is passed as the input to the second command.

By contrast, when you just run the second command on its own, `bar`, its input is inherited from the environment. In your case, that means the input comes from you typing at the console.

So, this:

```
openssl
```

runs `openssl` and lets you type input to it, whereas this:

```
echo -n | openssl
```

runs `openssl` with completely empty input — so it immediately sees end-of-file and exits.

(In many cases, it's still *possible* for a program to access the console and interact directly with you. But usually Unix-y programs are designed not to force themselves on you that way. If you redirect standard input to come from somewhere else, most Unix-y programs will respect that.)

Incidentally, a more conventional way to pass empty input to a command is to use the special always-empty file `/dev/null`:

```
openssl </dev/null
```